# jquery getJSON() not working while using YQL

Tags: jquery, yql

Hi I am using following code but it is not working as expected :

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%20%3D'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.box.net%2Fapi%2F1.0%2Frest%3Faction%3Dget_ticket%26api_key%3Dn9l0l065mp5ybfe8kuy6kwo5a3htx65w'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=cbfunc",
function(response) {
            window.ticket = response.query.results.response.ticket;
            window.location.href = 'https://m.box.net/api/1.0/auth/' + ticket;
});
```

the url given in getJSON is giving proper response in browser

am I hitting cross domain issue.what is the workaround.`YQL` is used for the cross domain requests, right?

Comment: Try to change `callback=cbfunc` to `callback=?` in the query. It once solved a  problem I had with YQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make the query with `callback=cbfunc` you have to pass a function with the name `cbfunc` as the second argument to `getJSON`. If you are using an anonymous function, as you do, you have to use `callback=?` in your query.

See also [this jquery plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/using-yql-with-jsonp/) (scroll to the end of the post).